# How can I determine which CMake targets were added by a command?

Tags: cmake, instrumentation, find-package, fetchcontent, build-target

I'm invoking a CMake command, e.g. `FetchContent_MakeAvailable()`, or `find_package()`. I want to determine which targets were added by invoking that command.

I'm ok with running some code before command as well as after it (so it can be some sort of a "set-difference" between lists of targets).